# How do I get data from a table based on reference value

Tags: datatables, unqork

I have created a data table in unqork.  How do I get data from that table based on a reference value.  For example the user enters a piece of data that resided in column A and I want to display the corresponding value from column C on my form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use data work flow. Filter the data using 
`_arg = < your Data  >` 
and extract the required data using formula component 
`[0].< column_name >`

Hope it will help you.